# CONCAT or TEXTJOIN and retain commas in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to concat the ROWID of a cell to a string of numbers and retain the commas. Works fine when no commas are present but if they are, it deletes them and makes it one long jumbled number. See screenshot. What am I missing?

Formula

[image]

Googled to no avail. I want cell H37 to read `2,164,216,521,662,160,-18` instead it reads `2164216521662160,-18`.

Comment: That is because it sees that as a number that is formatted to include the commas.  You should have formatted column F as text before entering the data in those cells.  Then the values would be seen as text and not a number.  At this point there is no reliable method to do what you want, unless you have different formula for each row.

Comment: if you are copy pasting the data from somewhere else, before pasting format all the cells in F as Text.  Then paste the values and then your formula will work.